# Calendar Libraries for C#

Tags: c#, calendar, libraries

Just wondering if anyone knew of any good Calendar libraries for C#? Something that handles the toaster pop up and tasks/events/notifications would be very good too (think MS Outlook)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scheduler component from telerik should do pretty much everything you need http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/scheduler.aspx

Comment: I have been using the Telerik libraries now for close to 12 months. Apart from a lot of weird encapulation they have improved the professionalism look of my applications three fold.

Comment: Nice one. Are they public sites or internal?

Comment: Oh sorry, I am using their WinForms Controls for C# development.